# How to disable one of Link components in a menu?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Sorry if the title does not present my question clearly.

```
<div className={"floated left column header-items " + this.props.active}>
  <Link onClick={this.headerItemClicked.bind(this)} className='home' to="/home" style={comStyles().headerItem}>Home</Link>
  <Link onClick={this.headerItemClicked.bind(this)} className='setting' to="/setting" style={comStyles().headerItem}>Setting</Link>
</div>
```

There is a header component with some links there. What I want to do now is to check if the current page is Home, then the Home link will be disabled.

My thought to do this is to check classname with the path. May I need if there are any more simple way that can achieve this?

My solution is as follows:

```
   headerItemClicked(e){
        if(e.target.className == this.props.active){
          e.preventDefault();
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like CSS `pointer-event` way. 
First you should not hardcode your `Link`, create array then loop it to render `Link` instead.

Then your component should be something like:

```js
const routes = [
{
  name: 'home',
  path: '/home'
},
{
  name: 'about',
  path: '/about'
}];

const listOfLink = routes.map((route) => (
  <Link to={route.path} disabled={this.props.active === route.name}>{route.name}</Link>
);
```

and then add css:

`a[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: sorry that i am new to js. Is that I can wrap the above codes with bracket and replace the hard code ones? It shows error when i do so

Comment: ah my bad. fixed it.